# RecyclerView with sticky header and sticky footer items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a RecyclerView similar with the following structure:

[RecyclerView with sticky header and footer items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUwkV.jpg)

It should be a **sectioned** RecyclerView with both **sticky header** and **sticky footer**.

With other words...each section (or item) should have a sticky header with scrollable content and a sticky footer.

Has anyone any idea on how to achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [Core-adapter](https://github.com/FarshidABZ/Core-Adapter) as RecyclerView adapter to handle your view types.

Comment: it doesn't seem to support sticky header of footers

Comment: @AndreiCosteiu, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a sticky header & footer to your recycler view, add a text field or a button you want to add as the header above the recycler view in your xml file. Similarly, add a footer below recycler view. It's better if you use Relative layout, which will consist a header text field, recycler view & footer. But by this method, the header & footer contents will be constant.

If you have to achieve sticky header like that of phone book contact list you can use this library
https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview

Comment: i need both sticky header & footer per list section. constant stickyheader and footer will not do. Something like  acombination of https://github.com/JohnKuper/recyclerview-sticky-footer and https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview for each section

Comment: ok, for that you can also go for one of the Android element called ExpandableListView. It has various methods for Group view & child view. Child view is the scrolling content and group view the Header. There are separate xml files for parent & child view. You can modify these and add one additional xml working as the footer, rest header & child are already present in this. It just expand on click. Make sure you make if visible by default, and not on click. You can refer http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: sadly ExpandableListView doesn't fit my needs either :(